# MYSYS2 mingw64 gcc can't link Shared Libary

Tags: c, gcc, ld, mingw-w64, lib

Hail,

I'm attempting to link to a compiled shared library to main, and it tells me it cannot find the library - despite linking to a static library of the same name in a different folder having no issues.  I am also able to make a shared library and link to it properly before trying to link to the library not in the current directory.

Perhaps I compiled it wrong or something, but here's the make files I used:

Makefile for external libraries:

```
all: objects libalpha.so libalpha.a

objects:
    gcc -fPIC -c file1.c file2.c

#shared lib
libalpha.so: objects
    gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,C:\libs\libc\lib\shared\alpha.so -o C:\libs\libc\shared\libalpha.so file1.o file2.o

#static lib
libalpha.a: objects
    ar rcs C:\libs\libc\static\libalpha.a file1.o file2.o
```

And here's the makefile for the main / internal libraries that do work before attempting to link to external libraries:

```
all: libtest libtwo libgroup.so libgroup.a main.o main_static main_shared

libtest: ./sub/libtest.c ./sub/libtest.h
    gcc -fPIC -c ./sub/libtest.c -o ./sub/libtest.o

libtwo: ./sub/libtwo.c ./sub/libtwo.h
    gcc -fPIC -c ./sub/libtwo.c -o ./sub/libtwo.o

#shared - compiles and links properly
libgroup.so: ./sub/libtest.o ./sub/libtwo.o
    gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,./sub/libtest.o ./sub/libtwo.o -o ./sub/libgroup.so

#static - compiles and links properly
libgroup.a: ./sub/libtest.o ./sub/libtwo.o
    ar rcs ./sub/libgroup.a ./sub/libtest.o ./sub/libtwo.o

#direct where the header files are located
main.o: main.c
    gcc -IC:\libs\libc\CODE\alpha -c main.c

#compiles fully and works
main_static: main.o ./sub/libgroup.a
    gcc main.o -L./sub -lgroup -LC:\libs\libc\static -lalpha -o main_static

#doesn't work man??
main_shared: main.o ./sub/libgroup.so
    gcc main.o -L./sub -lgroup -LC:\libs\libc\shared -lalpha -o main_shared
```

And here's the error:

```
ld.exe: cannot find -lalpha
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:27: main_shared] Error 1
```

And confirming they exist:

```
    Directory: C:\libs\libc\shared


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/1/2022   4:19 AM         224820 libalpha.so


    Directory: C:\libs\libc\static


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/1/2022   4:19 AM           2324 libalpha.a
```

See anything obvious?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: On Windows, shared libraries end with `.dll`, not with `.so`, so you should name it `libalpha.dll` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I see various errors;

1. You are generating position independent machine code (-fPIC). This is only needed in UNIX machines (BSD,Linux,...) but not on Windows. (Remove it.)
2. As pointed out by @ssbssa, shared libraries in Windows end with ".dll", not ".so".
3. Executables in Windows end with ".exe" (last two targets).